# K8s events logs not shown in Grafana Loki via promtail

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I have followed the blog at https://grafana.com/blog/2020/07/21/loki-tutorial-how-to-send-logs-from-eks-with-promtail-to-get-full-visibility-in-grafana/ in order to sent my `kubernetes events` logs to grafana loki but when I explore `{app="eventrouter”}` on `loki` it gives me `no matches found`.

`eventrouter` pod is displays correct logs but it doesn't reaches `promtail` to scrape it and send to `loki`.

- Evenrouter installed
- Promtail pipeline configuration changed

Expecting:

`{app="eventrouter”}` to display k8s events logs on grafana loki.

Comment: Are you able to to automate LogQL through the selection bar that appears after clicking on Explore > Log Browser? In order words is Loki configured correctly and are you able to read from other logs?

Comment: @Elazar yes all other logs are fine. This is the new stuff where I am shipping Kubernetes events logs Loki which is not working.